# What is the correct jquery syntax to check if an item is already in an array? Here is a simple example

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hollycotta/gb543/) to try different things.

The example asks the question: "How do I make the drop down show only 4 items, each instance of the same string only once?"

My if statement is incorrect, and I'm trying to find the correct way to set the if check.

HTML:

```
Project:<select id="projectList"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
 var projects = [];
 projects.push('<option value="0">- Select a Project -</option>');

 var c = [];
 c.push({project: 'Project 1'});
 c.push({project: 'Project 2'});
 c.push({project: 'Project 3'});
 c.push({project: 'Project 3'});
 c.push({project: 'Project 4'});
 c.push({project: 'Project 3'});

 for (var i = 0, j = c.length; i < j; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(c[i].project, projects) === -1) {
       projects.push('<option value="' + c[i].project + '">' + c[i].project + '</option>');
    }
 }

 $('#projectList').html(projects.join(''));
```

---  Update

After the first comment, I can ask the question in a different way:
"How would I restructure the javascript to populate this dropdown with only 4 distinct values then? Given that I have to use an array that will be sent to me like my variable c?"

Comment: @adeneo So how would I restructure the javascript to create a dropdown with only 4 distinct values then?  Given that I have to use an array that will be sent to me like my variable c?

Comment: Just an observation: There's no need to assign the c.lenght value to j in the condition of your loop.
Because you're not using the 'j' variable in the loop for anything else, you could've written your condition like this i < c.length

Comment: @Vash The Stampede I do that for performance so the length doesn't have to be re-evaluated each time.

Comment: I don't know... I find it redundant.  How much is it going to take the browser to re-evaluate the length? a fraction of a second? Besides, isn't it being re-evaluated when you're assigning j the length of c[]? Anyway, just giving my two cents. ;)

Comment: @Vash The Stampede  It does help as data grows larger, and I do need to code for best performance, so I do it this way. :)

Comment: You're right, it does make sense.  I was wrong to think it gets re-evaluated.  Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not comparing apples to apples. In your array, you're storing the whole option markup. In your check, you're just checking for the `Project n`.

I'd use something like:

```
var projects = ['<option value="0">- Select a Project -</option>'];

var c = [];
c.push({project: 'Project 1'});
c.push({project: 'Project 2'});
c.push({project: 'Project 3'});
c.push({project: 'Project 3'});
c.push({project: 'Project 4'});
c.push({project: 'Project 3'});

var seen = {};

for (var i = 0, j = c.length; i < j; i++) {
   var project = c[i].project;
   if (!seen[project]) {
      projects.push('<option value="' + project + '">' + project + '</option>');
      seen[project] = true;
   }
}

$('#projectList').html(projects.join(''));
```

Comment: I can't actually change the variable c in my real-life scenario.  It is an array of objects being sent to me externally.  Each object has a property called "project" that is a string.  I just need to create the dropdown so it has each value, but I don't want to repeat strings that are already present in the dropdown list.

May I re-ask it that way? :)   Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I'm not modifying the functionality of it, it's just a better way to initialize the array. You can ignore that part if you want.

Comment: Ok I'd just need the new variable "seen", I see.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique look-up table that checks if the name has already been output. Basically, add:

```
var names = [];
```

Then inside your for loop you'd check:

```
for (var i = 0, j = c.length; i < j; i++) {
  if (names.indexOf(c[i].project) == -1) { // unique project name
    projects.push('<option value="' + c[i].project + '">' + c[i].project + '</option>');
    names.push(c[i].project); // add it to lookup list
  }
}
```

This is, of course, assuming that the project name is the "key" and the only distinction between displaying it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it

```
$('#projectList').html(function() {
    return $.map(
        $.map(c, function(el) {return el.project;}).filter(function(el, index, arr) {
            return index == arr.indexOf(el);
    }),function(el) {
        return $('<option />', {value : el, text: el});
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gb543/2/)

Comment: I should also add that I want to keep my originally pushed "Select a Project".

Comment: @codesforcoffee - the first array value is a string, the others are objects, so it's totally different, and I would probably just solve it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/gb543/3/